# Configuring remote access on two different PCs behind one external IP

Tags: cisco, nat

I'm trying to set up outside access for a couple machines here using VNC.  They can both be accessed locally, and I was able to configure the first one for external access, but when trying to configure the second I get the error:

> The server address configuration overlaps with an existing translation rule.

I would like to use the same domain name to connect to, but differentiate based on port number.  So mydomain.com:5902 would go to one PC and mydomain.com:5903 would go to another.  I'm using a Cisco ASA 5510 with ASDM 6.4.

I set the DNS record up on our name server, and it works for the first one, but I keep getting the conflict error when trying to set the second one up through the "Public Servers" option in ASDM.  Is there something I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Static NAT is 1:1 -- Read up on PAT http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/security/asa/asa82/configuration/guide/config/nat_staticpat.html

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your config?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a static NAT rule that translates your internal hosts *to* their external equivalents.
Use the following commands (add in your public IP):

```
static (inside,outside) TCP *ExternalIP* 5902 10.0.1.81 5902 netmask 255.255.255.255
static (inside,outside) TCP *ExternalIP* 5903 10.0.1.82 5903 netmask 255.255.255.255
```

And then create the appropriate ACL rules to allow this traffic.